# Enable 3-finger swipe for home and end in Chrome

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, google-chrome, trackpad, multi-touch

3-finger left and right swipes on my trackpad work in Chrome.  They take me back one page in my history or right one page.  However, 3-finger up and down swipes does not appear to be implemented.

In Firefox and many other applications, an up or down swipe works the same way as hitting the home or end keys, respectively.

Is there any extension, application, or tweak that will enable this functionality in Google Chrome?

Comment: I see only in Firefox this is possible so far, not in Safari or Chrome. If somebody answers this Q, I am glad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

BetterTouchTool is the answer!
You can get it from [here](http://boastr.net/). It helps you configure all gestures globally or for a specific application. It also includes some special gestures not embedded by default on Mac OS.
With gestures, I can scroll through tabs, reload page, close tab, go up and down.

It works for the macbook trackpad, the Magic Mouse and the magic Trackpad.

A bliss ;)

Comment: Wow.  I just un-installed MagicPrefs 'cause I didn't find it customizable enough for my needs.  +1

Comment: is there a free/open source alternative?

Comment: @DanielLizik It was free at the time of the post (9 years ago!). As I don't use the magic trackpad anymore, I didn't realise it's not free anymore and don't know any alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Something that may be of interest is Chrome does support 3 finger swipe down, but it's semi-hidden; and not what you're looking for. But it's way cool. The way to access it is by simply typing about:flags into your address bar. You'll see the option at the top. It's called:

Tab Overview:
Swipe down with three fingers on your trackpad to see an overview of all your tabs. Click on a thumbnail to select it. Works great in fullscreen mode.

So this suggests that they will not be doing what you would like them to do. It would obviously conflict with Tab Overview. So you should look into an app like JiTouch if you want to get more customized gesture support. It will do what you're looking for.

My guess is that Google's next step will be to map fullscreen to 3 finger swipe up; especially given the emphasis Lion will be putting on fullscreen mode apps.

Comment: i was excited about this, but it seems gone: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/J5cfioQS4eg